# How to create a required filed using CHtml without model in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

```
<?php echo CHtml::checkBoxList('checkbox_list_name', '', array(
'Users' => 'All Users',
'Claim' => 'Claim Request',
'Business' => 'Add Business'
), array('id'=>'checkbox-list-id','class'=>'checkboxlist', 'required')). "<br>"; ?>
```

I have written the following code to make a checkbox and I want to make it a required field like in Html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You can add a `javascript` `function` to prevent form submission but this will fail if javascript is disabled so you should use both `javascript` and `server side validation`.

```
**Server Side validation**
```

1) Define a `variable` in your `model` (virtual variable)

Model.php

```
class Model extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */          
        public $checkbox_list_name;
```

2) Define it in safe rules inside your model

```
public function rules()
    {
 array('checkbox_list_name','safe'),
}
```

3) in your form.php

```
<?php echo $form->checkBoxList($model,'checkbox_list_name', array(
'Users' => 'All Users',
'Claim' => 'Claim Request',
'Business' => 'Add Business'
), array('id'=>'checkbox-list-id','class'=>'checkboxlist', 'required')). "<br>"; ?>

    <?php echo $form->error($model,'checkbox_list_name'); ?>
```

4) In YourController.php

Check that check boxes are checked or not

```
public function actionYouraction() {
        $model = new Model();
        $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if (isset($_POST['Model'])) {

            if($_POST['Model']['checkbox_list_name'] == ''){
                 $model->addError('checkbox_list_name', 'Select At least one!!!'); // this will through error if checkbox is not selected                   
            }else{

            $model->attributes = $_POST['Model'];
            $model->save();
        }
        $this->render('view', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
    }
```

**Javascript Method** - this will count the length of textboxes and retun false if not selected at least one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#user-form').submit(function() {// relace user-form id with your CActiveRecord form id
   if(!($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length)) {
    alert("Select at least one!!!");  
    return false;
}
  return true;
});

    </script>
```